# Sum between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables:

```
table1

date      value code
01-Jan-17   230 B2
01-Feb-17   100 B2
01-Mar-17   30  B2
01-Jan-17   56  C1
01-Feb-17   90  C1

table2

date    value   code
01-Apr-17   50  B2
02-Apr-17   160 B2
03-Apr-17   210 B2
04-Apr-17   130 B2
01-May-17   113 B2
02-May-17   106 B2
01-Apr-17   83  C1
02-Apr-17   20  C1
```

Sorry for not being clear from beginning, it's not simple as I mentioned before, I forgot to add two more conditions.

1) If in where condition I specify date (Mar 2, 2017) and if it's less or equal than max date of table1 then it should sum only table1 values and starting from beginning of year of specified date (Jan 1, 2017) till end of month of specified date (Mar 31, 2017). So sum in this case should be 360.

2) If in where condition I specify date (Apr 3, 2017) and if it's more than max date of table1 then it should sum values starting from beginning of year of specified date (Jan 1, 2017) till max date of table1 plus sum of beginning of next month (Apr 01, 2017) till end of month of specified date (Apr 30, 2017) of table2. And sum in this case should be 910.

thanks,
S

Comment: What's the part causing you difficulty?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

This is just `union all` and some `where` logic:

```
select sum(value), code
from ((select value, code
       from t1
       where dte >= date '2017-03-01' and dte < date '2017-04-01'
      ) union all
      (select value, code
       from t1
       where dte >= date '2017-04-01' and dte < date '2017-05-01'
      )
     ) vb
group by code;
```

Comment: sorry folks, I edited my initial question with additional conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is:

```
Select 
 (Select Sum(value) from table1
  where code = 'B2' 
    and date between DATE '2017-01-01' 
                 and DATE '2017-03-31')
   +
 (Select Sum(value) from table2
  where code = 'B2' 
    and date between DATE '2017-04-01' 
                 and DATE '2017-04-30')
```

but you could also do a union all

```
Select Sum(value) 
  from (Select code, value from table1 
        Where date between DATE '2017-01-01' 
                       and DATE '2017-03-31')
  union all 
       (Select code, value from table1 
        Where date between DATE '2017-04-01'
                       and DATE '2017-04-30')
 where code = 'B2'
```

Comment: Using strings for dates will mean Oracle will perform an implicit conversion using `TO_DATE( string, format_model )` where the format model is given by the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter and if it is not `DDMonYYYY` then the query will raise an exception. Each user can set their own session parameters and changing it will break the query without having changed the query. It would be better to use a date literal like `DATE '2017-01-01'` that does not rely on any implicit conversion or session parameters.

Comment: did not know that. Thanks. modified answer to reflect.